# Webpage communicating with locally running program

Tags: java, html, localhost

I need advice how to plan to design a project. My assignment is to take data from user through webpage and pass the data as an input to a program that should run locally on the computer. I imagine it as an application (to be installed), where user would type input into specific boxes and then after clicking run, the data would be additionally modified (to ensure correctness of input and some basic transformations) go to the program (written in Java) and after the result is computed then the results would be used for another computation to make the results easily readable (depicted in graphs, known distributions, some intervals etc.), and displayed to the user (also in the form of webpage).

I am not sure what is the process, what are the programs that I need to use (preferring open source and for free) for development of such a thing. I have not done this before and I need the advice what are the topics and areas that I need to do the research in.

I imagine steps similar to those.

1. have html page with CSS, containing JS functionalities
   (input boxes and interactive boxes for commands, such as send data)
2. make connection between html page and local server
3. send data from html form into program running on the server
4. let the program compute result from html input
5. process the result into user friendly format
6. send the data to be displayed on html page
   (graphically readable)
7. get to the html page in step 1.

Is something like this functional? How can I make the Java program run locally? Friend of mine mentioned to have it run on a port (how can I accomplish that)?
I can not have it run on internet, it needs to be as secure as possible (distributed to people but used separately). I have read about sockets, would that be good use in this case?

I would really appreciate tips how to proceed further.

Comment: It is not clear to me if you need any from of Connectivity to distribute Data? 
Or is any of the Data Handling on the local machine?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I am not sure if there is a way to create local server (running on the machine without internet) for the program to run and then how I can reach the server to pass the data from html page. Also how to make the connection between these two sides (server and html)